# Operations on View retrieved by findViewById(int) not reflected on UI

Tags: android, layout

I've absolutely no clue what's going on here. No operations on a view retrieved by `Activity.findViewById(int)` are reflected on the user interface.

The string "Set this text now!" (see below) should be set as the text of the text label, but it isn't. It just shows the initial text, as defined in the layout XML file.

**LoadingScreen** class:

```
public class LoadingScreen extends Screen {

    private TextView textLabel;

    public LoadingScreen(Screen parent) {
        super(R.layout.screen_loading, parent);
        this.textLabel = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.loading_text_label);
        this.textLabel.setText("Set this text now!");
    }
}
```

**Screen** class:

```
public class Screen {

    private int layoutResourceId;
    private int contentResourceId;

    public Screen(int layoutResourceId, Screen parent) {
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.parent = parent;
        loadLayout();
    }

    private void loadLayout() {
        if (this.parent == null) {
            this.uiManager.getActivity().setContentView(this.layoutResourceId);
        }
        else {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(this.layoutResourceId, null);
            ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) getActivity().findViewById(this.parent.contentResourceId);
            container.removeAllViews();
            container.addView(view);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, the follow applies:

- `Activity.findViewById(int)` doesn't throw a `NullPointerException`.
- The code is run on the UI thread, according to the fact that `Looper.getMainLooper().getThread() == Thread.currentThread()` returns `true`.

How to fix it?

Comment: Try invalidate TextView after set text like : this.textLabel.invalidate();

Answer (score 0):

If no `NullPointerException` is thrown, that means that the content view is loaded and that the UI should update the element which is to change (e.g. calling `setText(CharSequence)` to change the text).

The code snippet above looks okay. The problem did not lie in the snippet, but the fact that the method `loadLayout()` was called twice, caused the problem that the content view was reloaded, resetting all elements from the XML layout file to their initial value (e.g. a `<TextView>` with `android:text="My very own initial value"`).